# Postgres: join if field is not null in both tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to join two tables in Postgres, but only if the value is not NULL in both fields.

It *appears* to me that a query like this will actually behave like this already, without further conditionals:

```
SELECT * FROM aTable a JOIN bTable b on a.value=b.value;
```

This doesn't return rows from my database where both `a.value` and `b.value` are NULL.

However, I'm not totally confident I understand what's going on. Is this because `NULL` is not equal to `NULL` in Postgres?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`NULL` is a field property declaring absence of a value. For this reason nothing is equal to `NULL`, even `NULL` itself. If you want to join on `NULL`, you'll have to employ functions.

Few things you can try:

```
-- be sure `escape value` doesn't normally occur in the column to avoid surprises
on coalesce(a.value, 'escape value') = coalesce(b.value, 'escape value')
```

or

```
-- no need for escape values, but more difficult to read
on (a.value is null and b.value is null) or a.value = b.value
```

or

```
-- even more text, but intent is more clear (at least to me)
on case
    when a.value is null and b.value is null then TRUE
    when a.value = b.value then TRUE
    else FALSE
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually my case is fine as I want to join when *not* null, but this is a very helpful answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` is not equal to `NULL` in Postgres, so your condition does what you want.  This is the definition of `NULL` in SQL databases, so this applies to all databases.  This is true regardless of whether the condition is in a `where` clause, `on` clause, `case` expression, or anywhere else.

If you wanted them to be equal, then you can use `is not distinct from` in the `on` clause:

```
on a.value is not distinct from b.value
```